# Data Filter Scroll List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I'm using a vertical scroll list to scroll down 20 thumbnail images. I have 4 drop downs each with their own options.

EG:

Drop down 1 - Location (UK, US, Mexico, France)
Drop down 2 - Systems (Engines, Airframes)

Now when I select UK from drop down 1, all the images associated with the UK are filtered while the rest filter out. If I then select "engines" from the second drop-down the images associated with engines are shown while the rest filter out (this resets that I have chosen UK)

This shows engines from UK, US, Mexico and France.. rather than just the UK from the first drop down.
After choosing UK, then selecting Engines I want only the engines in the UK to stay and all engines inside the list to be removed. (engines from US, Mexico and France)

Advice would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this exact thing a while ago. The approach I took was as follows:

1. Define an array to store the options
2. Source the items from the array. With AngularJS this is easy, but with JQuery you'll probably have to define some method to refresh all select elements with data from the array.
3. Store the current value in each drop down in memory somewhere outside of the main array. (I believe I used a data attribute in the dom element.)
4. Modify the method that refreshes all elements to add the current value to the options list and then set the drop down's focus to the current value.

Once you have this body, the rest becomes easy. Selecting a value consists of the following three steps:

1. Append current value to array.
2. Update current value to new value you're selecting.
3. Refresh all select elements using your defined method.

Oh, and one last thing. Your current values are the values that are going to be used to determine whether to show or hide your thumbnails.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I did check this out, but it isnt something I can get to work. Thanks for your time and effort here though